# destroy always returns with the error callback (although everything seems to be ok)

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I'm trying to delete a model on my backend and what I do is this (the code is adapted just to show you the issue, some parts could be missing):

```
attending= new Backbone.Model();
attending.url= this.url() + "/reject";
attending.set({
   id: this.id
})

attending.destroy({
   success: function(){
      alert("yes");
   },
   error: function(){
      alert("no");
   }
});
```

but what I always obtain is a "no" alert. The fact is the backend seems to be updated correctly and what I obtain as a response too. Here it is:

[image]

so... what's wrong with the response I get? Why doesn't backbone recognizes it as a successful response? I get 200/OK and a "application/json" format as well!

Comment: Do you see any other request being made when the destroy is called

Comment: Pass in the arguments for the `error: function(model, xhr, options)` and check what the `xhr` object has to say

Comment: @Sushanth-- nope! It seems to be the only one sent

Comment: @Sushanth-- xhr seems to be OK! In fact, I'm using it to check if I got a 200OK code as a workaroung. And I get it! Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Your backend should return something with `200`

`jQuery` expect `200` with `application/json` to have some content

Have a look here: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2218#issuecomment-20991938

Comment: Thanks! It turned out to be an error that has to do with the empty body (no JSON objects are returned although the headers are well set)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to place a "debugger;" in the error callback and trace exactly why its coming that route vs the success route. That should atleast get your started on the right path...